# AsyncTask - Am I using it right?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm writing an Android app that displays random JPG images from the web. If a button is pressed, the app sends a GET request to *http://imgur.com/random*, and from the server's response it saves an URL to a JPG image as a String (see code).

I got this to work using *StrictMode.setThreadPolicy*, but I can't do it using AsyncTask.

I've tried to put the extraction of the .JPG address in *doInBackground*, and the actual process of changing the image in *onPostExecute*, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Page "http://imgur.com/random" redirects users to a random page;
    // After the redirect, the URL will be something like "http://imgur.com/gallery/XXXXXX";
    // Actual image is at "http://i.imgur.com/XXXXXX.jpg"
    private final String WHERE = "http://imgur.com/random";
    private ImageExtractor ie;

    private class ATask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Go to WHERE and get a valid URL to a random .jpg image
            ie = new ImageExtractor();
            ie.extractImageURL(WHERE);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Change the image in ImageView based on the new URL
            ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(ie.getImageURL()).getContent());
                i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    // Method called when the button is pressed
    public void getNewImage(View v) {
        new ATask1().execute("");
    }
    ....
}
```

---

```
public class ImageExtractor {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    private String imageURL;

    public void extractImageURL(String address) {
        String returnedURL;

        try {
            // Create URL object based on passed argument
            URL url = new URL(address);

            // Send GET request
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)(url.openConnection());
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

            // Response code of the answer
            conn.getResponseCode();

            // Create and save image URL as a string
            returnedURL = conn.getURL().toString();
            imageURL = returnedURL.replace("http://imgur.com/gallery/", "http://i.imgur.com/") + ".jpg";
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    // Return image URL as a string;
    // http://i.imgur.com/XXXXXX.jpg
    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }
}
```

Right now, if I press the button, the address of a random .JPG is stored correctly in imageURL, but nothing happens after that. Is it correct what I've done so far? Do I need to make a new AsyncTask/Thread for the BitmapFactory part, or something like that? How exactly should this be implemented?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the general concept but I'm curious about this bit:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(ie.getImageURL()).getContent());
```

You're doing this in `onPostExecute` which is on the UI thread, and this looks awfully like a network request. Newer versions of Android will just flat out refuse to do this and throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. It seems the only thing you're doing asyncly is the request to get the path to the image.

Comment: Thank you! It was silly of me. I moved that line up in `doInBackground` method and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

It looks ok to me. Just a thing: in the `doInBackground()` method you're returning `null` - Keep in mind that this is the parameter that your `onPostExecute()` method will receive, So basically `String result` will be null. But in your case, as far as you don't use it in an incorrect way, it's ok.

Answering your question: It's hard to tell where the error is, but the way you're handling your `AsyncTask` seems right to me. You don't need to declare a new `Thread` or `AsyncTask` to do the `extractImageURL(WHERE)` job, after all, `AsyncTask` is already a `Thread` and will do that in background. I'd consider putting several `Log.d()` instances across all your `AsyncTask` code to see where the error is, but as far as structure goes, it doesn't seem to have any issue.

Comment: I don't think saying "`AsyncTask` is a `Thread`" is fair. It is a component that creates a bacground `Thread` to do heavy-lifting but also offers methods to run things on the `UI Thread`

Comment: You're right, I probably described it in a very "brute" way.